# react-native FlatList prevent keyboard close on scroll, but close on press

Tags: react-native

I am using `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}` for the Flatlist prop. It seems that when I click on an item in the FlatList, it dismisses the keyboard, which is fine, but when i scroll I don't want it to dismiss the keyboard. It should only dismiss the keyboard when an item in the FlatList is pressed. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example, let's hope I completely understood your question. Check: https://snack.expo.dev/@zvona/dismissing-keyboard-on-item-click

The key solution is to have `Keyboard.dismiss()` on event listener for press. In addition to this, you should use `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}` instead.

Here is the relevant **App** code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [buttonPressed, setButtonPressed] = React.useState(-1);

  const handleItemPress = (index) => {
    setButtonPressed(index);
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(Keyboard.dismiss);
  };

  const getButtonPressed = (index) => {
    return buttonPressed === index ? 'green' : 'black';
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
    <Pressable
      style={[styles.item, { backgroundColor: getButtonPressed(index) }]}
      onPress={() => handleItemPress(index)}>
      <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{item}</Text>
    </Pressable>
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} />
      <FlatList
        data={['foo', 'bar', 'foz', 'baz']}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `InteractionManager`, which did help in resolving my issue. I kept the original `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}` and added a keyboard dismiss inside `InteractionManager`